# How to check if Query Cache is enabled in ArangoDB(3.1.23)

Tags: performance, caching, arangodb, aql

I have made configuration for query cache for Arango as follows
:

`{
    "mode": "demand",
    "maxResults": 2000
}`

**But we don't see any performance improvement despite of adding the above configuration.**
For fetching 40 documents the API takes around 265 ms for one concurrent thread.
In my query I have added an extra parameter of **"cache":true** and **"batchSize":40**.

How do we verify that the response is coming from cache and not from document.?

We have also enabled the logging of Arango to debug but not able to see any result from cache

Kindly help me with that.